# Dashboard app for Macs, are these cocoa based also?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I downloaded this Mac app that installed in my dashboard area, are these special apps or simply regular cocoa based apps that just installed in a specific area on my computer?

this is the app: http://bit.ly/8xKiH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Alexsander correctly answers, Dashboard widgets are miniature web apps: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  However, a lot of them are also powered by custom plugins, which *are* written in Cocoa.  [Check out the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashboard_ProgTopics/Articles/WidgetPlugin.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

A Dashboard widget is simply an HTML "project" that lives within its own sandbox in the Dashboard.